# Accessing variable defined above in object literal causes ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, variables, referenceerror

```
var g = {
    lang: "ttt",
    l: function(){
        console.log(lang);
    }
}

console.log(g.l());
```

> ReferenceError: lang is not defined

Why is lang undefined?

Comment: Or `g.lang` - without `()`

Comment: the `console.log(g.l())` is odd, should print `undefined` since `l` doesn't return.

Comment: It raises a ReferenceError because *only* `g` is a variable. There is thus no variable scoping issue, because `lang` is not a [local] variable.

Comment: (I cheated on the title. Anyway, "object literal" is a good search phrase here.)

Answer (score 5):

You need to use either `g.lang` or `this.lang`. `this` will refer to the `g` object, unless `.call()` or `.apply()` is used.

For example, this will result in undefined:

```
var g = {
    lang: "ttt",
    l: function(){
        console.log(this.lang);
    }
}

console.log(g.l.call(Math));
```

However, this will always give the right result (if you don't reassign `g`):

```
var g = {
    lang: "ttt",
    l: function(){
        console.log(g.lang);
    }
}

console.log(g.l.call(Math));
```

Comment: @pst Fair enough :P (But then `this.lang` wouldn't work either)

Answer (score 3):

Because `this` – unlike, say, Java – is never part of the scope chain lookup. The fix:

```
var g = {
    lang: "ttt",
    l: function(){
        console.log(this.lang);
    }
}

console.log(g.l());
```

Comment: "*scope chain lookup*" really is the wrong term here. Thats just about  function invocation and the value `this` references.

Comment: @jAndy I must respectfully disagree. `lang` is undefined because the runtime searches the scope chain looking for a variable named `'lang'` but does not find one. [`with(this)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) is another solution (albeit a bad one). Why does that work? **Because `with` "extends the scope chain for a statement."**

Comment: well, if you look at it from that perspective I would partially agree. However, the value of `this` as you know is still assigned dynamically, so `this` will only reference the object because its called as a `.method`. There is no scope chain lookup, its a straight reference to the object of invocation. I get your point now, but I still find it confusing a little.